# solution to wp_enqueue_script doesn't load jquery

Tags: wordpress

Hi I spend hours to figure out the problem why my own javascript doesn't work even in  html output  it seems loaded. I want to share it.

with these line of code

`wp_enqueue_script( 'myscrip', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/test.js',array('jquery'),NULL);`

it works properly problem was in my script file. I used jQuery "$" notation in my script and when I changed it to "$"->"jQuery" all worked normmaly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add jQuery like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

then register your own JavaScript like this:

```
wp_register_script('myplugin', plugins_url('/js/myplugin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('myplugin');
```

You can also add `$ = jQuery.noConflict();` before the ready function to make use of the "$" notation.

E.g.

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(
function() {
        $('#link').click(function(){alert('');});
    }
);
```